# Excel Visual Basic - executing a command if two cells in the same column are populated

Tags: excel, vba, macos

My first post here, so i shall try to make it as concise as possible.

I need to add some functionality into a spreadsheet that cannot use data validation. So i need it to be in visual Basic.

The code needs to run on a worksheet change, in the range of C4:SH5 (so only 2 rows but a lot of columns). If the two rows are populated in the same column then I need to execute a logic to msgbox.

for example:

```
 C4 & C5 <> "" then msgbox

 C4 = "" AND C5 <>"" then do nothing

 C4 <> "" AND C5 = "" then do nothing
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to check row 4 and 5 in all cells from col C to SH....? Do you want only a msgbox if they are same, or some code to run??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim myCol As Range

 For Each myCol In Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C4:SH5").Columns
  If myCol.Cells(1, 1) <> "" And myCol.Cells(2, 1) <> "" Then
   MsgBox "Both " & myCol.Cells(1, 1).Address & " and " & myCol.Cells(2, 1).Address & " are not empty"
  End If
 Next myCol

End Sub
```

Basically iterate over the columns in the specified range, and apply the condition to the cells in each column.